# MY-SQL table query giving incorrect result until i optimize the table

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `origin_post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ref_post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `broker_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isshared` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `deal_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `price_to` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `sector` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `protype` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sea_view` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sea_view_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `area` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `area_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `area_mesure_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `building_area` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `building_area_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `building_area_mesure_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `bathrooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bathrooms_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rooms` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rooms_to` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float NOT NULL,
  `lng` float NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `map_data` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `shape_data` text NOT NULL,
  `seo_title` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `seo_keywords` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `seo_description` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `publish_date` date NOT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date NOT NULL,
  `request_status` enum('','NEW','ACCEPTED','REJECTED') NOT NULL,
  `request_date` date NOT NULL,
  `accept_date` date NOT NULL,
  `share_per` float(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `deal_completed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `completed_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `deal_type` (`deal_type`),
  KEY `price` (`price`),
  KEY `sector` (`sector`),
  KEY `protype` (`protype`),
  KEY `sea_view` (`sea_view`),
  KEY `area` (`area`),
  KEY `building_area` (`building_area`),
  KEY `bathrooms` (`bathrooms`),
  KEY `rooms` (`rooms`),
  KEY `lat` (`lat`),
  KEY `lng` (`lng`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `price_to` (`price_to`),
  KEY `sea_view_to` (`sea_view_to`),
  KEY `area_to` (`area_to`),
  KEY `building_area_to` (`building_area_to`),
  KEY `bathrooms_to` (`bathrooms_to`),
  KEY `rooms_to` (`rooms_to`),
  KEY `request_status` (`request_status`),
  KEY `request_date` (`request_date`),
  KEY `accept_date` (`accept_date`),
  KEY `ref_post_id` (`ref_post_id`),
  KEY `deal_completed` (`deal_completed`),
  KEY `location` (`location`(255)),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `country_code` (`country_code`),
  KEY `expiry_date` (`expiry_date`),
  KEY `origin_post_id` (`origin_post_id`),
  KEY `completed_by` (`completed_by`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_location_description` (`title`,`location`,`description`),
  CONSTRAINT `posts_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `app_users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=833 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

When I run `select count(id) from posts where deal_completed='1' and user_id='<anyuserid>'` then it gives zero records always but when I optimize this table then it's giving correct result and after some time I need again to optimize the table.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your problem?

Comment: Optimizing a table should not be changing the data.  More importantly, an aggregation query without a `group by` should *always* be returning one row.  The value of the *column* might be 0, but the number of records would always be 1.

Comment: price is never FLOAT. It's why DECIMAL was invented

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not aggregation issue. same issue with this query " select id,title from posts where deal_completed='1' and user_id='<anyuserid>' "

Answer (score 0):

May be it is because of too many key you are using. Key should only be used if you are going to search table using that column or order by that column which makes operation fast. If not required do not use too many keys, as you have optimize the table again and again. Try to normalize the table as much you can and try to use FOREIGN KEYS. And as @Tim said if it is an int try int.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. All keys are using in search so i can't remove any one.